# Rmarkdown and Shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm attempting my first Markdown doc and everything has been going smoothly until
I get the error

> ```
>  "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'input' not found"
> ```

with this chunk

```
{r, echo=FALSE}

inputPanel(
radioButtons("category",label= "Select  Category",choices=c("diffPts","diffGF","diffGA","diffGD","diffpos"),inline = TRUE)
)
   renderPlot({
   ggplot(clubSeason, aes(x=team, y=input$category)) + geom_boxplot()
})
```

if I hardcode e.g `y="diffPts"` the chart displays. Putting a `print()` around the ggplot does not help

TIA

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following runs fine for me. The value of ìnput$category` is printied as expected

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
inputPanel(
   radioButtons("category",label= "Select  Category",choices=c("diffPts","diffGF","diffGA","diffGD","diffpos"),inline = TRUE)
)
renderPlot({
   print(input$category)
   ggplot(faithful, aes(x=eruptions, y=waiting)) + geom_boxplot()
})
```
````

UPDATE:

The issue appears to be with the `aes` function being passed a string. You can use `aes_string` instead:

```
renderPlot({
   ggplot(clubSeason, aes_string(x='team', y=input$category)) + geom_boxplot()
})
```

Comment: Tx. I think the issue may be that input$category is say, "diffPts", whereas I need it to be diffPts. I'm sure there is a way round this but I cannot recollect it offhand

Comment: @pssguy maybe use aes_string(x='team', y=input$category) rather then calling aes directly. If you could give a reproducible example that gives the error I think something like `aes_string` might work.

Comment: That appears to be solution! I had not come across that before Thanks very much. Do you want to amend the answer so that I can give you the credit