# passing string as column

Tags: r, shiny

I am quite new to r programming language. I am working on a shiny web application which has a selectInput that I want each graph to use. So the selectInput gives me names on the column I wish to analyse. Here is an example of my input.

```
selectInput("Calculation", "Select Calculation",
            choices = c("PriceAverage", "SalesValue", "SalesQuantity", "StockValue",
                        "StockQuantity", "PurchasesValue", "PurchasesQuantity"))
```

Now the problem is that I want it to feed the choice as a column name and not as string because the argument does not take string, I have also tried to convert it's datatype using various functions such as the one below `as.name(Calculation)`. How do I pass the Name of a column in string format as a column so that my ggplot function understands it as a column? Code is below.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$RetailPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    ProductGroup    <- input$ProductGroupName
    Region    <- input$RegionName
    ProductLevel    <- input$ProductLevel
    Calculation    <- input$Calculation
    #bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    RetailData = as.data.table(RetailData)
    RetailData.filtered = RetailData[RegionName == Region & ProductGrouppName == ProductGroup, ] 
    summarized.Selection = RetailData.filtered[, list(StockQuantity=sum(StockQtyUnits), 
                                             StockValue = sum(StockValue), 
                                             PriceAverage = mean(PricePerUnit)), 
                                      by=c("MonthDate", ProductLevel)]
    ggplot(summarized.Selection, aes(x = MonthDate, 
                                     y = **as.name(Calculation)**, 
                                     fill = ProductSKUName)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.4)


# draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
#hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

})
```

Comment: Search for `aes_string()`/`aes_q()`/ `aes_()`. There are plenty of existing question about this

Comment: I guess this is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701775/passing-column-name-via-selectinput-in-shiny-application)

Comment: Thank you guys, I don't know how I missed that, I thought I had looked everywhere, can't believe it is that simple... Thanks for the help.